# What authentication method should I use in SQL server connection string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, service, windows-services, connection-string

I have a question regarding the credentials used in SQL server connection string. Basically I create a windows service to handle my SQL database procedures (Insert, Select, Delete and Update etc.), this service is logged on as a special windows user I create with sufficient database permissions, it doesn't log on as Local System. Other windows accounts don't have SQL server permission.

So what do I use in my connection string?

Do I use Integrated Security= true ? Or do I use my special user credentials?

Thank you for reading

Comment: If the service is running as the special user, then just Integrated Security=true should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Integrated Security=true` if you want the same user that your windows service is running under to access the database.